# Kafka topic creation: Timed out waiting for node assignment

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to set up the following on a **single remote AWS EC2 machine**.

1 Kafka Zookeeper
3 Kafka brokers
1 Kafka topic

I have done the following:

I have created two copies of the **server.properties** file and named them **server_1.properties** and **server_2.properties**, where I changed the following values:

**broker.id=0** to **broker.id=1** and **broker.id=2** respectively

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092 to  advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://3.72.250.103:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://3.72.250.103:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://3.72.250.103:9094  in the three config files

changed **log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs** to
**log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs_1 and log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs_2**  in the respective files

All three brokers start up fine, and

```
bin/zookeeper.sh localhost:2181 ls /brokers/ids
```

shows all three brokers

But when I try to create a topic like:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 --create --   partitions 5 --replication-factor 1 --topic cars
```

the command times out with the error message: *Timed out waiting for node assignment*

**What have I tried:**
I tried creating only **one** broker - that worked fine
I tried creating the topic with *--bootstrap-server localhost:9092* only - that did not work

I tried changing **listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092** to **listeners=PLAINTEXT://3.72.250.103:9092** and for the 2nd and 3rd broker respectively - I was not even able to start the brokers with this configuration.

I am not sure what to try next

Comment: Please try one broker only, first. Or did you, and it worked fine? Why not use MSK?

Comment: One broker works fine. 

The internet simply tells me to set listeners = PLAINTEXT://your-ip:portnr as well as the advertised.listeners. However, if I change the listeners away from PLAINTEXT://:portnr, then the brokers wont start with an advertised listener specificed.

I am not using MSK, since I am trying to learn how to use Kafka and how it works in general, and thus I would like to get it working with a simple setup using the base componenets, before I use a managed service :(

Comment: "The internet tells..." Where? Provide a link. You don't need AWS to learn Kafka. You could use Docker https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-single-kafka-multiple.yml